# Read text file with with name between X and Y bash

Tags: bash, file, variables

I'm making a bash script to make it easy for other system admins to read a certain folder with log files. So far the script reads two variables, $STARTDATE & $ENDDATE. For every day there is a log file, in this case called YYYY-mm-dd.log. I want the script to output the contents of all the log files with a name that is equal to or in-between the two variables.

for example:
If I enter a $STARTDATE of 2015-01-18, and an $ENDDATE of 2015-01-20, I want the script to output the contents of:

- 2015-01-18.log
- 2015-01-19.log
- 2015-01-20.log

It there an easy way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest removing the `-`s and the `.log` from the file names, and then just counting from the resulting start date to the end date... Or going the other way around, format your dates as `YYYYmmdd`, count between the two dates, and reformat the date string to make a matching file name. Which of those approaches is better depends on the rest of your code, though, which I have no idea about..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bash and can guarantee that the log filename format is consistent then you should be able to use something like this.

```
startdate=$1
enddate=$2

for logfile in /path/to/logfiles/*; do
    lf=$(basename "$logfile" .log)
    if [[ "$lf" > "$startdate" && "$lf" < "$enddate ]]; then
        echo "### $logfile"
        cat "$logfile"
    fi
done
```

Note that I used lowercase `startdate` and `enddate`. General practice is that `ALL_UPPER` variables are reserved for the shell/etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
dir=.
STARTDATE=2015-01-04; ENDDATE=2015-01-12
dates=`find -s "$dir" -name '*log' | sed -e 's@.*/@@' -e 's/\..*//' | while read file; do [ $file \< $STARTDATE -o $file \> $ENDDATE ] || echo $file; done`
for date in $dates; do cat "$dir"/$date.log; done
```